# How to fix SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above in symfony?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, libpq

I am following the symfony fast-track book at [symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/6.2/the-fast-track/en/1-tools.html).
But when I want to create an entity class with:

```
$ symfony console make:entity Conference
```

I got this error:

```
An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above
```

The DATABASE_URL is set like this from the tutorial:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=15&charset=utf8"
```

I have tried with and without this in .zshrc

```
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
```

I am on MacOS with M1.
I guess it is because in the tutorial Postgresql is used. I have not installed that. I have installed MariaDB. I followed the same tutorial but set MariaDB in the .env settings. There it is working.

Meanwhile I have installed libpq with brew. At the end I got this message:

```
libpq is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because conflicts with postgres formula.

If you need to have libpq first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find libpq you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include"
```

I have added the path to .zshrc and also the export flags. creating an entity class is still not working.

Comment: Please post all code/errors in the question as text instead of images, since text in images aren't indexed or searchable for future visitors that might have the same issue.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  You don't want to use postgresql, and you report that using mariaDB works.  So what is the issue?

Comment: The tutorial is with postgresql. 
But I am thinking to switch to mariaDB.

Comment: If PostgreSQL throws that error, are you sure this is a problem of PHP or Symfony?